# Is there anything to do with order of writing scope for client credential flow in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, scopes, clientcredential

I am trying to call a get API that gives patient details from Cerner EHR. I am using the system based SMART app. But when I am trying to call it, I get an error

> invalid scope.
> 'scope':' system/Observation.write system/Patient.read system/Patient.write system/Observation.read'

I tried this in postman and CURL both works perfectly fine.

But when I am giving the scope as - `'scope':'system/Patient.write system/Patient.read system/Observation.write system/Observation.read'` i.e. giving system/Patient.write or any other scope as the first scope I can`t get the details of patients, I have to give system/Patient.read as the first scope itself then only I can read the patient details. I don't understand why the order of scope matters here.

The code for getting access token is given below:

```
const getAuth = async () => {
 try{
    const token_url = 'token-url endpoint';
    const data = qs.stringify({'grant_type':'client_credentials','scope':'system/Patient.write system/Patient.read system/Observation.write  system/Observation.read '});
    console.log(data)
    const opts = {
    headers: { 
      'Authorization': `Basic ${auth_token}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Length': '61',
      'Connection':'close',
      'cache-control': 'no-cache'  
     }
    };

    const response = await axios.post(token_url, data, opts);
  
    return response.data.access_token;

  }catch(error){
    console.log( error);
  }
}
```

After this, I am calling a function to get the patient details , the function code is given below:

```
async function getFunction(){
    const bearer_token=await getAuth();
  
  const get_url = 'get endpoint';
  const get_header = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${bearer_token}`,
      'Accept': 'application/json+fhir'
   }
  }
    console.log(bearer_token);
     
      const get_respone = await axios.get(get_url, get_header);
      let data = get_respone.data;
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    
    }
```

but shows the error as :

> data: {
> resourceType: 'OperationOutcome',
> issue: [
> {
> severity: 'error',
> code: 'forbidden',
> diagnostics: 'Bearer realm="fhir-ehr-code.cerner.com", error="insufficient_scope"',
> expression: [ 'http.Authorization' ]
> }
> ]
> }

But if I am taking the access token by changing the scope as :

```
'scope':'system/Patient.read system/Patient.write system/Observation.write  system/Observation.read'
```

Then I will get the patient details since I have added the `system/Patient.read` scope at the beginning of the scope.

I am using Node.js as the backend for this SMART App and I am a beginner in Node.js, so I can't figure out why the order of scope matters in calling an API. Does anyone know this?

Comment: Can you add more details to the question like - how are you calling an API, when did you receive an error, body and some details to look and debug?

Comment: I have added more details please check , Thanks @ApoorvaChikara

Comment: So, you are requesting data from `Cerner EHR` using the above API and you need to keep the scope data in order?

Comment: Yes, means I need to read patient details, observations and also need to create patient also, but if I need to do these multiple actions I need to change the scope for each action I am doing, but instead, I wish to keep the scope as it is like that of the postman(postman will do the HTTP request irrespective of the scope order ). In other words, I am trying to do the exact things we are doing in potman with help of Nodejs .

Comment: With the current details, I am not sure why this happens. It post can request data without the order then your app should do the same. Is there any other error like CORS or anything else?

Comment: No other error at all. So basically in Nodejs, the scope need not be bothered about order right?